# Any workarounds for this MSVC specific vector<unordered_map<Trivial, NonCopyable>> bug?

Tags: c++, move, stdvector

The following code does fail on MSVC but compiles on GCC and Clang, [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/eGc5cbGWo)

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct NonCopyable
{
    NonCopyable() = default;
    NonCopyable(NonCopyable const &) = delete;
    NonCopyable(NonCopyable &&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    using Data = unordered_map<int, NonCopyable>;

    vector<Data> vec;

    vec.reserve(3);     // error
    vec.resize(3);      // error
    vec.emplace_back(); // error

    return 0;
}
```

This is the simplified version of the case I stumbled while working on my project. I was using MSVC from the beginning so I would prefer a workaround (if possible) rather than changing the compiler.

As I understand from the error messages, `vector` tries to copy construct a `pair<Trivial, NonCopyable>`. Which,, it shouldn't,,, but there is no way I know of to tell it not to do that :/

- When `Data = map<int, NonCopyable>` MSVC fails with the same errors, while others compile.
- All compilers are fine if I use `Data = pair<int, NonCopyable>;` so the container trying to copy construct a pair might be the unorderd_map
- It works if I construct the vector with the correct size. However, I can not do that in my case.

Thanks

Comment: You can report this issue to https://github.com/microsoft/STL

Comment: One interesting note, with my vs2019 the first line that errors is the emplace_back not the resize or reserve.

Comment: What error messages do you get from MSVC? Edit them into the question (it could help someone else that has this problem find your question).

Comment: @Genjutsu, the issue is already there: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1036

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently this is a long time know bug with a combination of MSVC STL implementation choices and Standard specifications...

The issue I found when I was going to submit a bug report, from 2018:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C2280-when-modifying-a-vector-containing/377449

- This error is present in MSVC 2017 and after.
- It seems like <strike>not</strike> going to be fixed. (see @Alex Guteniev's comment)

The explanation given:
https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6q94ai/chromium_windows_builds_now_use_clangcl_by_default/dkwdd8l/

- There is a workaround: `vector<Wrapper<unordered_map<int, NonCopyable>>>`, where the Wrapper is also a non-copyable type.

Comment: Not exactly it is not going to be fixed. For `unorederd_map` the fix can be done, see https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1036#issuecomment-661742697